# Multiple inputs in a single line using scanf()?

Tags: c++, c

I used `scanf()` function and realized that I could input only one number into an array using it. Is there any way to read the whole number in a single line?

ex:

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
     {
     scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
     }
```

I wanted to read all the 5 digits in a single line.. Hope I'm clear enough!

Comment: `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4]);` note that `scanf`wants an address (not a value) use `&`

Comment: if you're concerned about hitting enter each time then u can also write 5 numbers giving space b/w them and then hit enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `scanf ("%d %d %d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4]);`

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a single source code line, you could use either:

```
scanf ("%d %d %d %d %d", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2], &arr[3], &arr[4]);
```

or:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) scanf ("%d", &(arr[i]));
```

If you meant a single input line, both those are fine as well. The `%d` will skip leading white space in the stream so it makes little difference whether you enter:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

or:

```
1
2
3 4
5
```

I prefer the loop version myself since it can be made arbitrarily large without making your source code line way too long.

Answer (score 1):

Though you want it in array . A number of `5` digits can be stored in single `int` variable (depending on what is size of `int`  on your system).

In a single `scanf` you can do this -

```
scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3],&a[4]);
```

This -

```
 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",arr[i]);  //you missed &  should be scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
  }
```