# How to make "overloaded" scanf in C?

Tags: c, scanf

**Friends how can I make Scanf to take 1 or 2 or 3 numbers depending on input data I give?**

- sample data 1:  "1 2 5"
- sample data 2:  "1 4"
- sample data 3:  "4"

> 

```
 if(scanf("%lf",&a)==1 )
    {
        printf("1 input num\n");
    }
    else if(scanf(" %lf %lf",&a, &b)==2 )
    {
        printf("2 input num\n");
    }
    else if(scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a, &b, &c)==3 )
    {
        printf("3 input num\n");

    }else
    {
        printf("Error message.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Read line with `fgets` and parse it later.

Comment: Mika Hasanov, There are ugly ways to do this with `scanf()`, yet elegant ways with `fgets()/strtol()`.  Consider discarding `scanf()`.  Your call.

Comment: you can solve this problem using for loop very easily.

Comment: @KayesFahim Let's just give good advice rather than solving problems with `scanf` that we wouldn't have without it.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider this an answer:

```
    int InputNums=0;
    
    InputNums = scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a, &b, &c);
    
    if(InputNums!=0)
    printf("%d input num\n");
    else
    printf("Error message.\n");
```

It works by NOT eating one number and then trying whether instead more numbers could have been read, like your shown code does.
Instead try to read three numbers and then let `scanf()` tell you how many worked.

But actually I am with the commenters. If you do not have guaranteed syntax in your input (which `scanf()` is for) then use something else.

This is nicely describing which alternative in which situation AND how to get scanf to work in the same situation:

http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Of course, the problem with this is that it can consume input spanning any number of lines.  If the scan is supposed to avoid crossing line boundaries (not stated, but plausible) then this does not reliably achieve that.

Comment: That is true. But nothing in the questions asks for a solution to that and any scanf for three numbers like shown in OPs code has the same problem. For once I am not guessing beyond the question.

Answer (score 0):

Scanf already does this for you, and indeed you used the same scanf function with a variable number of arguments. You can look here: [How do vararg work in C?](https://jameshfisher.com/2016/11/23/c-varargs/)

However you don't need to overload scanf, but rather pass to it a string telling what you need to scan. [You can do this dynamically by changing the string at runtime](https://onlinegdb.com/i31rM1vVlZ).

The code to try is the following:

```C
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{   
    char one[] = "%d";
    char two[] = "%d%d";
    
    int o1;
    int t1,t2;
    
    scanf(one,&o1);
    scanf(two,&t1,&t2);
    
    printf("%d %d %d",o1,t1,t2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The point of the question seems to be that the OP *doesn't* know in advance exactly what (how many numbers) they need to scan.  Although they used the term "overload", what they seem really to want to do is adapt to the input presented.

Comment: Couldn't they build up the string by stacking as many "%d"s as many required by the user? Then use such built string as the first parameter of scanf

Comment: It is possible and occasionally useful to build format strings dynamically.  But for the present question, do refer back to the "doesn't know in advance" bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you *must* use `scanf()` ....

`"%lf"` is a problem as it consumes leading white-space including `'\n'`, so we lost where a line of input might have ended.

Instead first look for leading white-space and see if an `'\n'` occurs.

```
#define N 3
double a[N];
count = 0;

while (count < N) {
  // Consume leading white-spaces except \n
  unsigned char ch = 0;
  while (scanf("%c", &ch) == 1 && isspace(ch) && ch != '\n') {
    ;
  }
  if (ch == '\n') {
    break;
  }
  // put it back into stdin
  ungetc(ch, stdin);

  if (scanf("%lf", &a[count]) != 1)) {
    break;  // EOF or non-numeric text
  }
  count++;
}

printf("%d values read\n", count);
for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
  printf("%g\n", a[i]);
}
```

---

Alterantive to consume various multiple leading whitespaces that only uses `scanf()` with no `ungetc()`:

```
// Consume the usual white spaces except \n
scanf("%*[ \t\r\f\v]");
char eol[2];
if (scanf("%1[\n]", eol) == 1) {
  break;
}
```

---

If the line contains more than N numbers or non-numeric text, some more code needed to report and handle that.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of using fgets, strtok and atof  to achieve same:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char input[256];
    double inputsf[256];
    
    while(1) {
        printf(">>> "); fflush(stdout);
        char *s = fgets(input, 255, stdin);
        if (!s)
            break;
        int count = 0;
        char *t;
        while (t = strtok(s, " \n")) {
            s = NULL;
            inputsf[count++] = atof(t);
        }
        printf("Found %d inputs\n", count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            printf("  %lf\n", inputsf[i]);
        
        if (count == 0)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Bases on the @chux-ReinstateMonica comment, here is a piece of code which uses *strtod*. It skips leading spaces, but has an issue with the tailing spaces at the end of the string. So, some extra checking is needed there, which could be used for error checking as well. The following loop can replace the strtok loop from above.

```
    while(*s) {
            char *e;
            double val = strtod(s, &e);
            if (e == s)
                break; // not possible to parse, break the loop
            inputsf[count++] = val;
            s = e;
        }
```

Comment: Some improvements possible: 1) 256 ok w/fgets --> `fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin);`  2) Other white-spaces exist other than `' '` and `'\n'`.  3) Consider `strtod()` rather than `strtok(), atof()` - better error handling.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sure, it can be improved. However, *strtod* from your suggestion will require additional statements for skipping spaces, so it is not necessarily an imrovement.

Comment: `strtod()` (and `atof()`) skip leading spaces, negating the need for `strtok()`.  `atof()` does have UB on overflow and no-convert.  `strtod()` does not have that problem, thus an improvement.

Comment: You are correct, it skips leading spaces and can replace both.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to problems with `scanf` and `fscanf` is usually to use something other than `scanf` or `fscanf`.  These are remarkably powerful functions, really, but also very difficult to use successfully to handle non-uniform data, including not only variable data but data that may be erronious.  They also have numerous quirks and gotchas that, though well documented, regularly trip people up.

Although `sscanf()` shares many of the characteristics of the other two, it turns out often to be easier to work with in practice.  In particular, combining `fgets()` to read one line at a time with `sscanf()` to scan the contents of the resulting line is often a convenient workaround for line-based inputs.

For example, if the question is about reading one, two, or three inputs *appearing on the same line*, then one might approach it this way:

```
char line[1024]; // 1024 may be overkill, but see below

if (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL) { // else I/O error or end-of-file
    double a, b, c;
    int n = sscanf(line, "%lf%lf%lf", &a, &b, &c);

    if (n < 0) {
        puts("Empty or invalid line");
    } else {
        printf("%d input num\n", n);
    }
}
```

Beware, however, that the above may behave surprisingly if any input line is longer than 1023 characters.  It is possible to deal with that, but more complicated code is required.

Comment: You will note distinct similarities with Yunnosch's answer, as theirs is a good approach but for the line-spanning issue.  On the other hand, if you want to scan a sequence of numbers that is permitted to span multiple lines then Yunnoch's is an outstanding answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem using those line of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

int a[100];
int n;
printf("How many data you want to input: ");
scanf("%d", &n);


printf("Sample %d data Input: ", n);
for (int i=0; i <n; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &a[i]);
}

printf("Sample data %d: ", n);
for (int i=0; i <n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
}

if(n == 1){
     printf("\n 1 input num\n"); 
}else if(n==2){
     printf("2 input num\n");
}else if(n==3){
     printf("3 input num\n");
}else{
    printf("Error");
}



return 0;
}
```

if you want to take multiple input in single line use this line

```
int arr[100];
scanf ("%lf %lf %lf", &arr[0], &arr[1], &arr[2]);
```

Comment: And if the problem to be solved is "adaptively read an input consisting of a variable number of numeric fields *without an explicit field count*"?  Because that does seem to be the question.

Comment: that cannot be possible on that way may be, because when you input 1 digit and press enter for another 1 it will print the first line , program will never execute 2nd and third term.

Comment: (1) The question seems to suppose that multiple input fields would be provided on the same line.  However, (2) you are mistaken: one `scanf()` call will happily consume input fields spanning multiple lines.

Comment: you can't do that on this way , for multiple input in single line you have to write a lot of code.

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Yunnosch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69711475/2402272), or else study `scanf`'s docs a bit more.

Comment: either you can use loop for input or you can use something like that : check link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779305/multiple-inputs-in-a-single-line-using-scanf

Comment: In any event, the point is that however much code a solution to the OP's problem might take, the approach presented in this answer is not such a solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238516/discussion-between-kayes-fahim-and-john-bollinger).