# Detect two type of input in C

Tags: c

Assume that i have two types of query
one is 1 2 3
and the other one is 2 3

if the head (index 0) is 1, then the total number within the input are 3 `(1 2 3)`
and if the head is 2 then the total number within the input are 2 number  `(2 9)`

How do I detect it? Thank you

The problem that I have is that I scan the 3 of them
 `scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b&c)`

so, when I only have total of 2 number in the input `(2 3)` The program wont continue

Thank you

Comment: You *can* call `scanf` multiple times you know? Call it once to get the first number and then call it a second time with the right format based on that. TBH a better approach would be `fgets` to read the line and then `sscanf` to parse the integers. The return value of `sscanf` will tell you how many numbers were successfully parsed.

Comment: Please explain "The program wont continue", I doubt it. I think a [mre] is needed to demosntrate that.

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69711230/how-to-make-overloaded-scanf-in-c/69711475#69711475 i almost think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the return value of `scanf()` to detect this, and you should generally always check return values. They are given for a purpose.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    printf("Please enter 2 or 3 numbers: ");
    int n = scanf("%d%d%d", &a, &b, &c);
    switch (n) {
    case 2:
        printf("You have entered 2 numbers, %d and %d\n", a, b);
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("You have entered 3 numbers, %d, %d and %d\n", a, b, c);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Well, you made an error.\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

*Note 1: Even `printf()` returns a value, commonly the number of characters printed. In this simple example, we can ignore it.*

*Note 2: It is always a very good idea to read the documentation of functions you use, if you don't know them in detail.*